# error using azure devops api for python "API resource location is not registered"

Tags: python, azure-devops

I want to extract users list from azure devOps using python but an error appears:

```
ValueError: API resource location 229a6a53-b428-4ffb-a835-e8f36b5b4b1e is not registered on https://vssps.dev.azure.com/(my Organization).
```

I have already tried to extract the projects list and it works fine.

here is my code:

```
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication


personal_access_token = 'my personal access token'
organization_url = 'https://dev.azure.com/(my Organization)'

credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)

accounts_client = connection.clients_v5_1.get_accounts_client()
get_acc = accounts_client.get_accounts()

for acc in get_acc:
    print(acc)
```

btw I need to get information about the last access and date created account so maybe another method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in API, it's fixed now

Answer (score 0):

There is a call in Azure DevOps API called "User Entitlements - Get User Entitlements" with documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/get%20user%20entitlements?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

It provides a list of users for a specific project with details like lastAccessDate and dateCreated.

Is this something you find useful?

Comment: It could be but I need userId attribute to call this method, are you aware of how can I get the list of user id?